# Are numpy string arrays faster than python strings

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating a string that is about 30 million words long.  As you can imagine, this takes absolutely forever to create with a for-loop increasing by about 100 words at a time.  Is there a way to represent the string in a more memory-friendly way, like a numpy array?  I have very little experience with numpy.

```
bigStr = ''
for tweet in df['text']:
  bigStr = bigStr + ' ' + tweet
len(bigStr)
```

Comment: What are you doing with the string once you've created it? do you need to create the string at all? If all you are doing is getting a length then do that

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Loading all words into memory? If that is not the case you want to look into 'generators'

Comment: The question is which operation is more expensive? Looping through the data or appending the string?

Comment: `bigStr` is, and will be, a regular Python `str` value, no matter what compatible type `tweet` may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a string, use `' '.join`, which will create the final string in O(n) time, rather than building it up one piece at a time, which takes O(n^2) time.

```
bigStr = ' '.join([tweet for tweet in df['text']])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're trying to get the length of all data. For that you don't need to append all strings. (And I see you add a white space for each element)

Just get the length of `tweet` and add it to an integer variable (+1 for each white space):

```
number_of_texts = 0
for tweet in df['text']:
  number_of_texts += 1 + len(tweet)

print(number_of_texts)
```

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have included the len() function.  That was just for curiosity.  I need the array of strings so I can convert each unique word to an int.